# menu list: some items are not displayed

Tags: css, html-lists

I have 11 items to display in my menu and I just see 9 elements.

Example:

[image]

Is there a trick to adapt the menu list according to the screen?

I think to reduce the font size is maybe solution to solve my problem?

I don't know if you have a better solution?

I share you my code HTML/CSS.

Thank you so much for your help.

```css
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */

@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}
.header {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}
.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.mainInner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.mainInner div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.25px;
}
#sidebarMenu {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  transform: translateX(-250px);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  /* background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FC466B 0%, #3F5EFB 100%); */
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.sidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}
.sidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 22px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}
.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.diagonal.part-1 {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -9px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="header"></div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu" />
      <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
         <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
         <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
         <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
      </label>
      <div id="sidebarMenu">
         <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
            <li>
               <a routerLink="account-opening">
               <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Ouverture d'un compte</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="portfolio">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Selection d'un portefeuille</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="corporate-action">
               <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Corporate actions</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="visualization-deposit">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Visualisation des dépôts</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="value"> <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Valeurs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="indice-boursier">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Indices Boursiers</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="devise"> <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Devises</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="valuable-table">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Tableau de valeurs</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="form-create">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Création formulaire</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="form-delete">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Suppresion formulaire</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="form-follow-up">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Suivi formulaire</a
                  >
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove **height: 100%; position: fixed;** from **#sidebarMenu** and you'll be allowed to scroll and see all items.

Comment: Is there a trick to adapt the menu list according to the screen? 
Yes, There is a `fit-content` property.
Also, since you have set height:100% in most of your elements. And in many scenarios you may required, `overflow` property. Best to learn few responsive we design  course and move forward

If required, you can use `min-height` instead, as per your required.

There are so many ways to handle these senarios also. You may use flexbox or grids to setup your layout and adjust elements within the right way.

Happy Coding!
Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to increase the `width` of `#sidebarMenu` to fit all items into one line each, and reduce the top and bottom `padding` on the list items (`.sidebarMenuInner li`). Also the `transform` parameter of `#sidebarMenu` has to be adapted to `translateX(-310px)` (or whatever value you chose for `width`) in this case:

```css
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */

@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}
.header {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}
.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.mainInner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.mainInner div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.25px;
}
#sidebarMenu {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 310px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  transform: translateX(-310px);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  /* background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FC466B 0%, #3F5EFB 100%); */
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.sidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}
.sidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 22px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}
.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.diagonal.part-1 {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -9px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="header"></div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu" />
      <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
         <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
         <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
         <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
      </label>
      <div id="sidebarMenu">
         <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
            <li>
               <a routerLink="account-opening">
               <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Ouverture d'un compte</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="portfolio">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Selection d'un portefeuille</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="corporate-action">
               <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Corporate actions</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="visualization-deposit">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Visualisation des dépôts</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="value"> <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Valeurs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="indice-boursier">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Indices Boursiers</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="devise"> <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Devises</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="valuable-table">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Tableau de valeurs</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="form-create">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Création formulaire</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="form-delete">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Suppresion formulaire</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="form-follow-up">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Suivi formulaire</a
                  >
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First run this snippet and see whether you want something like this if yes then you just need to add `overflow-y: scroll` to your `#sidebarMenu`

```css
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */

@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}
.header {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}
.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.mainInner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.mainInner div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.25px;
}
#sidebarMenu {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; /*Added only this */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  transform: translateX(-250px);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  /* background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FC466B 0%, #3F5EFB 100%); */
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.sidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}
.sidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 22px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}
.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.diagonal.part-1 {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -9px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="header"></div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu" />
      <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
         <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
         <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
         <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
      </label>
      <div id="sidebarMenu">
         <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
            <li>
               <a routerLink="account-opening">
               <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Ouverture d'un compte</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="portfolio">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Selection d'un portefeuille</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="corporate-action">
               <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Corporate actions</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="visualization-deposit">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Visualisation des dépôts</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="value"> <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Valeurs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="indice-boursier">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Indices Boursiers</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="devise"> <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Devises</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="valuable-table">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Tableau de valeurs</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="form-create">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Création formulaire</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="form-delete">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Suppresion formulaire</a
                  >
            </li>
            <li>
               <a routerLink="form-follow-up">
               <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Suivi formulaire</a
                  >
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```